# Problema con un trigger de tipo update en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo dos bases de datos en el mismo servidor, P_1 y P_2.
En P_2 tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE alumno (
  id_alumno int(11) NOT NULL,
  no_cuenta_alumno char(9) NOT NULL,
  apellido_paterno_alumno varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  apellido_materno_alumno varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  nombre_alumno varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nombre de pila',
  generacion_alumno int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_nacimiento_alumno date NOT NULL,
  sexo_alumno char(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=Masculino, 2=Femenino',
  clave_carrera_alumno int(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Clave de la carrera',
  activo_alumno tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 -> Alumno activado\r\n0 -> Alumno desactivado',
  email_alumno varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  email_alumno_alterno varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_registro_alumno timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  actualizado int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  tipo varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Alumno, Profesor, Pruebas, Administrador',
  sesion_alumno tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id_alumno),
  UNIQUE KEY cuenta_UNIQUE (no_cuenta_alumno)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Los siguientes triggers:

```
~
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ToInsertDataBD2
    AFTER INSERT ON alumno
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO P_1.alumnos
    SET
        alum_cuenta = NEW.no_cuenta_alumno,
        car_clave_fk = NEW.clave_carrera_alumno,
        alum_nombre = CONCAT(NEW.apellido_paterno_alumno,' ',
            NEW.apellido_materno_alumno,' ',NEW.nombre_alumno),
        alum_nacimiento =  NEW.fecha_nacimiento_alumno,
        alum_generacion = NEW.generacion_alumno,
        alum_correo =  NEW.email_alumno,
        alum_avance = NULL,
        alum_promedio = NULL,
        alum_sesion = NEW.sesion_alumno;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
~

~
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateDataBD2
    BEFORE UPDATE ON alumno
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.email_alumno != OLD.email_alumno THEN
        UPDATE P_1.alumnos
        SET 
            alum_correo = NEW.email_alumno
        WHERE alum_cuenta = OLD.no_cuenta_alumno;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
~
```

Pero el segundo trigger no hace nada, mientras que el primero si funciona pero mo me muestra ningún error.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo reproducir el problema:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `P_2`.`alumno`, `P_1`.`alumnos`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `P_1`.`alumnos` (
    ->   `id_alumno` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `alum_cuenta` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    ->   `alum_correo` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id_alumno`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `cuenta_UNIQUE` (`alum_cuenta`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `P_2`.`alumno` (
    ->   `id_alumno` INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `no_cuenta_alumno` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    ->   `email_alumno` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id_alumno`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `cuenta_UNIQUE` (`no_cuenta_alumno`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `P_2`.`InsertDataBD2`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `P_2`.`UpdateDataBD2`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `P_2`.`InsertDataBD2`
    ->   AFTER INSERT ON `P_2`.`alumno`
    ->   FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     INSERT INTO `P_1`.`alumnos`
    ->     SET
    ->         `alum_cuenta` = NEW.`no_cuenta_alumno`,
    ->         `alum_correo` =  NEW.`email_alumno`;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `P_2`.`UpdateDataBD2`
    ->   BEFORE UPDATE ON `P_2`.`alumno`
    ->   FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   IF NEW.`email_alumno` != OLD.`email_alumno` THEN
    ->     UPDATE `P_1`.`alumnos`
    ->       SET 
    ->         `alum_correo` = NEW.`email_alumno`
    ->     WHERE `alum_cuenta` = OLD.`no_cuenta_alumno`;
    ->   END IF;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `alum_cuenta`, 
    ->   `alum_correo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `P_1`.`alumnos`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `no_cuenta_alumno`, 
    ->   `email_alumno`
    -> FROM
    ->   `P_2`.`alumno`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `P_2`.`alumno`
    ->   (`no_cuenta_alumno`, `email_alumno`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('123456789', 'email@alumno.sql');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `alum_cuenta`, 
    ->   `alum_correo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `P_1`.`alumnos`;
+-------------+------------------+
| alum_cuenta | alum_correo      |
+-------------+------------------+
| 123456789   | email@alumno.sql |
+-------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `no_cuenta_alumno`, 
    ->   `email_alumno`
    -> FROM
    ->   `P_2`.`alumno`;
+------------------+------------------+
| no_cuenta_alumno | email_alumno     |
+------------------+------------------+
| 123456789        | email@alumno.sql |
+------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `P_2`.`alumno`
    -> SET `email_alumno` = 'alumno@email.sql'
    -> WHERE `no_cuenta_alumno` = '123456789';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `alum_cuenta`, 
    ->   `alum_correo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `P_1`.`alumnos`;
+-------------+------------------+
| alum_cuenta | alum_correo      |
+-------------+------------------+
| 123456789   | alumno@email.sql |
+-------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `no_cuenta_alumno`, 
    ->   `email_alumno`
    -> FROM
    ->   `P_2`.`alumno`;
+------------------+------------------+
| no_cuenta_alumno | email_alumno     |
+------------------+------------------+
| 123456789        | alumno@email.sql |
+------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo, el error se daba con el trigger de la otra base de datos, se generaba un deadlock ya que la tabla que afecto de la otra base de datos tiene un trigger de tipo update que afecta la tabla de esta base de datos